# Replace an element or selector with a shortcode in WordPress (wpml)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wpml, wordpress-shortcode

On this website: https://librarytreehouse.it

I would like to replace the social link at navbar top left and insert a [WPML](https://hr.wikipedia.org/wiki/WPML) shortcode to display the WPML switcher.

```
do_action('wpml_add_language_selector');
```

How can I solve it?

With JavaScript or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The *header.php* file is where the WordPress menu is and there you can insert the social media icons.

Otherwise, if you have to modify the switcher that is created by a PHP function (language-selector.php) or you can get more help by reading about it in *[Custom Language Switcher](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/custom-language-switcher/)*.

Most probably you know it, but for adding the switcher for social media, you can get the code from *[AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/)*.